# python regex: match to the first "}"

Tags: python, regex

I have a string `s` containing:-

```
Hello {full_name} this is my special address named {address1}_{address2}.
```

I am attempting to match all instances of strings that is contained within the curly brackets.

Attempting:-

```
matches = re.findall(r'{.*}', s)
```

gives me

```
['{full_name}', '{address1}_{address2}']
```

but what I am actually trying to retrieve is

```
['{full_name}', '{address1}', '{address2}']
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I assume that there is no cases like `'Hello {full_{what}}'`

Comment: @ony was just gonna ask that

Comment: Nope. no cases of `{full_{what}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> text = 'Hello {full_name} this is my special address named {address1}_{address2}.'
>>> re.findall(r'{[^{}]*}', text)
['{full_name}', '{address1}', '{address2}']
```

Comment: And @jamylak is the fastest gun in the West.

Comment: Funnily enough I have the only different approach

Comment: for `text = "The wonderful {wizard{of{oz}}}"` or  `"The wonderful {wizard{of{oz}"` this produces a match of `{oz}` which may or may not be the expected or desired result.

Comment: @Li-aungYip I asked OP if we need to be able to handle that, no response yet. Also the question asks for regex solutions... It would be pretty hard to write a regex capable of parsing that type of input

Comment: @Li-aungYip, having `'{wizard{of{oz}'` - probably is less desired result. I vote for more strict regexps. That's why I dislike regexps that uses '?' modificator.

Comment: I am not expecting something like `{wizard{of{oz}}}`. I only care about instances of `{whatever_word}` so this solution suits me fine. :) Thanks @jamylak

Answer (score 2):

Try a non-greedy match:

```
matches = re.findall(r'{.*?}', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need a non-greedy quantifier:

```
matches = re.findall(r'{.*?}', s)
```

Note the question mark `?`.

Comment: This regex mathes with `'{xx{ttt}'`

Comment: @jamylak, yes that is typo. *matches*. I.e. if you have string like 'a {xxx_{yyy}_zzz} b` this will give `['{xxx_{yyy}']`.

Comment: @ony As I said before, it would be almost impossible and really tedious to try and parse that with regex alone